# Python for loop posting json to url?

Tags: python, json, rest, for-loop

The following code works but only uploads the one result at the index as per the below, see `['result'][2]["text"]` - which uploads the `'text'` result at index 2 perfectly:

```
with open("test.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    connection.request('POST', '/1/batch', json.dumps({
        "requests": [{
             "method": "POST",
             "path": "/1/classes/test",
             "body": {
                 "playerName": data['results'][2]["text"],
                 "Url": data['results'][2]["Url"],
                 "Amount": data['results'][2]["Amount"]
             }
         }]
    })
```

How can I loop through all of the json results here (`[0]` to `eof`) rather than having to change `['results'][0]["text"]`, press enter, `['results'][1]["text"]` press enter, `['results'][2]["text"]` press enter etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple [`for`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) will solve it:

```
with open("test.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for entry in data['results']:
        connection.request('POST', '/1/batch', json.dumps({
            "requests": [{
                "method": "POST",
                "path": "/1/classes/test",
                "body": {
                    "playerName": entry["text"],
                    "Url": entry["Url"],
                    "Amount": entry["Amount"]
                }
             }]
     })
```

If you really need the index number, you can use the [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function:

```
 for index, entry in enumerate(data["results"]):
     # ...
```

**Edit:**

If by `'/1/batch'` you mean `'/2/batch'` (eg. typo), then you will need to use `enumerate()`. Eg:

```
with open("test.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for index, entry in enumerate(data['results']):
        connection.request('POST', '/%d/batch' % (index), json.dumps({
            "requests": [{
                "method": "POST",
                "path": "/%d/classes/test" % (index),
                "body": {
                    "playerName": entry["text"],
                    "Url": entry["Url"],
                    "Amount": entry["Amount"]
                }
             }]
     })
```

Comment: I think OP really needs the index number. Look at the url he or she is posting to: /1/batch