# building REST url's with for loop using JSON data, python

Tags: python-3.x, rest

Fist time to ask a question:

I am reading in a JSON file that looks like this (goes on for several thousand lines):

{'L_602356450160818666': ['Q2LD-49YE-FLNT', 'Q2LD-8ZVQ-4QBN', 'Q2LD-9MU6-PUV8', 'Q2LD-DYTG-T274'], 'L_602356450160818156': ['Q2LD-CYS8-V6KR', 'Q2LD-6RPL-HGWK', 'Q2LD-79A3-CPBF', 'Q2LD-D2VF-Q9DN']}

What I want to achieve is to build URL REST end points via a for loop, sample below:

url construction:

```
url = "baseurl + '/networks/" + str(networkID) + "/devices/" + str(serial) + "/uplink"
```

example:

```
url = "baseurl + '/networks/" + L_602356450160818666 + "/devices/" + Q2LD-49YE-FLNT + "/uplink"
url = "baseurl + '/networks/" + L_602356450160818666 + "/devices/" + Q2LD-8ZVQ-4QBN + "/uplink"
```

and so on... and loop through a key and its values and move to the next key and its values.

So far I have:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
   jsonObj = json.load(f)


for networkID, serial in jsonObj.items():

    url = "baseurl + str(networkID) + "/devices/" + str(serial[0]) + "/uplink"
```

Obviously its just reading each line and one value, need to keep reading the same key and build the url until all values are read for that key, then move to the next key, build url etc. Do I need a for loop with in a for loop or While? Do I need to pull out each serial with serial[0], serial[1] .....

I found question [Python for loop posting json to url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21690567/python-for-loop-posting-json-to-url), however could not relate to what Im trying to do.

Help appreciated.

tks

Answer (score 0):

It finally dawned on me that all I need to do was read a single key and iterate over its values, and then put the output into a for loop to build the URL. A simple list compression.

```
jList = [[k,v] for k, values in jsonObj.items() for v in values]

for i in jList:
     url = "baseurl + i[0] + "/devices/" + i[1] + "/uplink"
```